# Django queryset filter for blank FileField?

Tags: python, django

How do I perform a Django queryset filter looking for blank files in `FileField` fields?

The field isn't null, it has a FileObject in it that doesn't have a file.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8850415

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I was having this issue too, and finally found the solution!

```
no_files = MyModel.objects.filter(foo='')
```

This works because internally, the `FileField` is represented as a local file path in a `CharField`, and Django stores non-files as an empty string `''` in the database.

Comment: Thanks. I still cannot find anything about this in the docs.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution:

```
no_files = MyModel.objects.filter(foo__in=['',None])
```

Comment: As for me it is more full solution than above. Few my models required varchar fields that allow Null values.