# Django - FileField check if None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with an optional file field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  sound = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True)
```

---

Let's put a value

```
>>> test = MyModel(name='machin')
>>> test.save()
```

---

Why do I get that ?

```
>>> test.sound
<FieldFile: None>
>>> test.sound is None
False
```

---

How can I check if there is a file set ?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
if test.sound.name: 
     print "I have a sound file"
else:   
     print "no sound"
```

Also, `FileField`'s boolean value will be False when there's no file: `bool(test.sound) == False` when `test.sound.name` is falsy.

Comment: Which boolean value ? Do you mean `test.sound is False` ?

Comment: Not `is` - test.sound won't have the same identity as `False`. However, `if test.sound: print "yes"`, `else: print "no"` should print no. `bool(test.sound)` should be `False`.

Comment: +1: `bool(fieldFile)` is `False` when `fieldFile.name` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5213095/9785224) from a different question, you can try this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  sound = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True)

def __nonzero__(self):
    return bool(self.sound)
```